# Removing decimal from string

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm trying to understand how I can remove a decimal. I have tried `Math.trunc()` but it never seems to remove. `Logger.log(esValues.length)` prints 500.0, I tried adding `var removeDecimal = Math.trunc(esValues.length)` then printing removeDecimal but I still get 500.0

```
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var es = ss.getSheetByName("School1");
  var ms = ss.getSheetByName("School2");
  var hs = ss.getSheetByName("School3");
  var esValues = es.getDataRange().getValues();
  var counterDell = 0;
  var counterHP = 0;
  //var esValues = es.getRange('A:C').getValues();
  Logger.log(esValues.length); //This prints 500.0, Also tried adding here Logger.log(Math.trunc(esValues.length))
  for (var i = 0; i < esValues.length; i++) {
    var data = esValues[i];
    var first = data[1];
    var last = data[0];
    var middle = data[2];
    var studentid = data[3];
    var device = data[4];
    if (device.includes("Dell")) {
      counterDell++;
    } else if (device.includes("HP")) {
      counterHP++;
    }

  }
  Logger.log(`Dell count is ${counterDell}`)
  Logger.log(`Hp count is ${counterHP}`)
}
```

Comment: [`Math.trunc` returns a number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/trunc). What you want is a string. Use `toFixed(0)`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to format numbers as currency strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149055/how-to-format-numbers-as-currency-strings)

Answer (score 2):

```
Logger.log(esValues.length.split('.')[0])
```

breaks the decimal into integer and decimal portions, then we discard the decimal portion.

Comment: I think @Cooper's answer is correct, .length wouldnt be decimal anyway and the Logger API must be formatting it within. Which i believe makes this answer incorrect for OPs purposes

Answer (score 2):

Actually just not using the logger will elimate the .0.  For some stupid reason it has always done that.

```
function lfunko() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var es = ss.getSheetByName("School1");
  var vs = es.getDataRange().getValues();
  var counterDell = 0;
  var counterHP =
  for (var i = 0; i < vs.length; i++) {
    var device = vs[4];
    if (device.includes("Dell")) {
      counterDell++;
    } else if (device.includes("HP")) {
      counterHP++;
    }
  }
  const msg = `HP: ${counterHP} DELL: ${counterDell}`
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(msg),"Counts");
}
```

Comment: Do I need to create a function that adds a menu also for this to work? Using it alone doesnt seem to give me a dialog

Comment: try it again...

Comment: hmm, did something change here? Looks the same. I dont get a dialog on the sheet ```const msg = `HP: ${counterHP} DELL: ${counterDell}`
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(msg),"Counts");```

Comment: I just tested it and it works for me. I changed this line: `var device = vs[4];`

Comment: Sorry, maybe Im not understanding the full process. If I run this within apps script I get error Exception: Cannot call SpreadsheetApp.getUi() from this context. When I goto the spreadsheet and refresh or open nothing seems to happen? Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: I ran the code from within apps script and it ran just fine.   I don't understand why opening the spreadsheet or refreshing should do anything with regard to the script.  Are you trying to run it from a trigger?

Comment: i think this is the answer, i was wondering why the .0 would show up at all in a length prop. the Logger API mustve been what was formatting the number that way, im sure there are config params in the Logger API.

Comment: @MattPengelly yeah maybe I never really let it bother me too much.  I just moved on to debugging my code and move on.

Comment: @Cooper No trigger trying to be used, wasn't sure if I needed one? I get same error:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70895185/exception-cannot-call-spreadsheetapp-getui-from-this-context

Comment: Well I cannot reproduce the error